# Freeze last frame of animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, sdk, freeze, imageview

Is there a way to freeze the last frame of my animation in my iphone app?  Here's my code so far.

```
popup.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture3.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture4.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture5.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture6.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture7.png"], nil];
        popup.animationDuration = 1.750567;
        popup.animationRepeatCount = 1;
        [popup startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview:popup];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animation stops UIImageView shows UIImage set in its `image` property. So you should just set it to the last frame of your animation:

```
popup.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture7.png"];
```

Comment: You have no idea how happy you just made me with this simple answer.  Thank you very much!!